# Java equivalent of Oracle's TRUNC function?

Tags: java

In my PL-SQL work, I've come to regularly use the TRUNC function to check higher-position values in numeric IDs.  for example:

```
if trunc(idValue,-3)=254000 then...
```

Is there a similar method available for int/Integer variables in Java?

Comment: `Math.round` or `Math.ceil` and some computation most likely

Answer (score 1):

You could take advantage of integer division here:

```
public int trunc(int value, int places) {
    // places should be positive, not negative
    int divisor = Math.pow(10, places);
    int tempVal = value / divisor;
    int finalVal = tempVal * divisor;
    return finalVal;
}
```

(somewhere in your code)

```
if (trunc(idValue,3)==254000)
```

Comment: I think you meant to use power in divisor (`int divisor = Math.pow(10, places);`), not multiplication,

Comment: Thank you @Mureinik